# Load Grid view data on scroll down

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Hii I am using a grid with more than 1000 rows (from database). I was using Paging. a new requirement is to remove paging and show only 50 records at first load and then when user scrolls the page down and reaches to bottom of grid, show next 50 records and so on.. I really dont have any idea about it can any one plz help .... I am using VB.net with 4.0 framework.
following is my code to display grid

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/abc.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TM.aspx.vb" Inherits="TM" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server" ID="ctn">
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="gvGrid" runat="server" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#6495ED" BackColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#6495ED">
                         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DDEEFF" />
                         <Columns >
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10px">
                             <HeaderTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="Chk_All_ALert" runat="server" onClick="checkboxAll_click('gvGrid',this.checked,'chk_Alert');"></asp:CheckBox></HeaderTemplate> 
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                   <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chk_Alert" value=<%#Eval("UniqueID")%> onclick="CheckUncheck_All('gv_AlertHistory',this.checked,'gvGrid','chk_Alert');"/>
                                   <%--<input type="hidden" id="hdnIDAlert" value=<%#Eval("SchoolID")%> runat="server"/>--%>
                             </ItemTemplate>    
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                              <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                               <HeaderTemplate>Date/Time</HeaderTemplate>
                               <ItemTemplate><%#DisplayTime(Eval("SentDate"))%></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField>
                               <HeaderTemplate>Email Subject</HeaderTemplate>
                               <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Subject")%></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField>
                               <HeaderTemplate>Email Text</HeaderTemplate>
                               <ItemTemplate><%#GetAlertGridMessage(Eval("Message"))%></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                         </Columns>
                         </asp:GridView>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please explain why you have put c# here as well? My guess would be to do this without postback it will be javascript

Comment: sorry for that !! Yes this is without post using javascript

Answer (score 2):

you should use 'Jscroll' or follow this example this may be helpful to you

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx